# How to implement POST Requests for my Google Cloud Functions using JWT

Tags: node.js, post, google-cloud-platform, axios, google-cloud-functions

```
exports.pdftoData = (req, res) => {

jwt.sign({ foo: 'bar' }, serviceAccount.private_key, { algorithm: 'RS256' }, function(err, token) {
    console.log(token);
    
    //return res.json({ message: `Token Generated `, jwtoken: token, pdfData: req.body.pdf_name});

    axios.post('https://us-central1-ayan-ai.cloudfunctions.net/function-1', req.pdf_name,
    {
    headers: {
      'authorization': 'bearer '+ token
    }}).then(res => {
      
      console.log(res)
      return res.json({ message: `Data Fetched successfully`});


    }).catch(err=>{
    console.log(err)
    return res.json({ message: `Data Not Fetched `+err});
    })

    
    
  })
```

} **I have Written this code but everytime my functions goes to the data not fetched case how to fix it and it happens throgh the postman also please help me to fix this code??**

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What is the security of your Cloud Functions? What is your current error? Do you want to use your Node code or Postman?

Comment: I want to get a function response using my node code , I have a service account json file but don't know how to get response from the fiunction endpoint link

Comment: Does this help you? https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service#nodejs